# How to declare concept function signature with a template type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

Is there a way to have a concept function signature that has a template argument?

Something like this:

```cpp
template<typename SomeTypeT, typename U>
concept SomeType = requires(SomeTypeT s) {
    { s.SomeFunction<U>() };
};
```

?

Comment: You have a concept and its template parameter having the same name `SomeTypeT`. This is not a good idea. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Right. My bad. concept name should be `SomeType` instead of `SomeTypeT`. I have just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown concept definition works, except that you need to tell the compiler that `SomeFunction` is a template:

```
template<typename SomeTypeT, typename U>
concept SomeType = requires(SomeTypeT s) {
    { s.template SomeFunction<U>() };
};
```

This is always necessary if you want to reference a template member of a dependent name in a template definition, not specific to concepts. When parsing the definition, the compiler doesn't know yet what type `s` is and so can't know that `SomeFunction` is supposed to be a template. But it needs to know, since the meaning of the angle brackets and the whole expression can dependent on it.